# Building a vending machine interface as console app but getting error - can't convert a double to a bool

Tags: c#, .net

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double creditsvalue;
        string inputString;

        double totalvalue;
        string InputString;

        double checkout;
        string INputString;

        Console.WriteLine("Hi");Console.WriteLine("The items and their prices are as follows:");
        Console.WriteLine("Chocolate bar at 0.80");
        Console.WriteLine("Soda can at 0.70"); 
        Console.WriteLine("Soda bottle at 1.25"); 
        Console.WriteLine("Crisps at 0.50");
        Console.WriteLine("Cookies at 1.10");
        
        Console.WriteLine("How many credits to you want to add to your account?"); 
        inputString = Console.ReadLine();
        creditsvalue = double.Parse(inputString);
        Console.WriteLine("Is this amount {0} correct", creditsvalue);
        Console.ReadLine();

        Console.WriteLine("Which items would you like to have?");
        InputString = Console.ReadLine();
        totalvalue = double.Parse(InputString);
        Console.WriteLine("The total is {0}", totalvalue);

        double accountvalue = creditsvalue - totalvalue;

        Console.WriteLine("Would you like to checkout or add more things?");
        INputString = Console.ReadLine();
        checkout = double.Parse(INputString);

        if (checkout);

    }
```

this is the code I have so far please help me out cause I am really stuck. it says that I can't convert a double to a bool and back if I try to change it into a bool.

Comment: an `if` statement requires a `bool`.  You are passing a `double` to it, which doesn't make sense.  I'm guessing what you want is the user to input `Y` or `N` (or similar), then parse that to a `bool`.

Comment: If your input is "y" or "n" then you'll need to compare your INputString with it. `checkout = INputString.ToLower().Equals("y")`

Comment: What value do you expect `iNputString` (and consequently `checkout`) to contain? What is the user allowed to input?

Comment: It's unrelated to your issue and not a problem, here (yet), **but**: do not use floating point types for representing monetary amounts.

Comment: what do you expect `if(0.3)` to do? `checkout` is a number, nothing you can use within an if-statament.

Comment: ^^ _"nothing you can use within an if-statament"_ unless you go on to use it in an expression in the if statement, like `if ( x < 0.3 )` which resolves to a boolean value and can be "processed" by the if.

Answer (score 0):

First, change the type of the `checkout` from double to bool:

```
bool checkout;
```

And then change the parsing logic to something like this

```
Console.WriteLine("Would you like to checkout or add more things?");
INputString = Console.ReadLine();
checkout = INputString.ToLower().Equals("yes");

if (checkout) {
   // Your code here
}
```

Note:
In the code we're expecting the user to write "yes" to checkout.
If you'd like to type something else, then just replace that word with your desired word.

Comment: Might be worth noting that the question in the writeline is unhelpful or ambiguous as the user could be tempted to write "checkout" or "add more things" as the answer. It's not a yes/no question :-)